# It is not like this is going to cause any/some problems. - what are the differences?

Tags: word-choice, usage

**Example 1**

> It is not like this is going to cause **any** problems.

**Example 2**

> It is not like this is going to cause **some** problems

**Example 3**

> It is not like this is going to cause problems

Is **Example 3** correct?

What are the differences between **Example 1** and **Example 2**?

Answer (score 2):

(1) and (3) mean the same; (2) is not idiomatic. (We say *not any*, we don't say *not some*.)

Comment: Agreed. (2) doesn't make sense. (3) is best because it is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your example (3) is correct. If "it" causes no problems then (1) and (3) are both true, and if "it" causes at least one problem then (1) and (3) are both understood to be false. However (1) is stronger, especially if "any" is emphasised.

The second example (2) is unusual, and it may not be understood to mean the same thing as (1). The reason is connected with how English deals with negation.

The two sentences "this will cause some problems" and "this will not cause some problems" are not exact logical opposites. The first means that some problems will be caused, and its logical opposite is that no problems will be caused. However the second only means that some problems will not be caused, and does not exclude the possibility that other problems might be caused. The sentence that is the logical opposite of "this will cause some problems" is "this will not cause **any** problems".

In your sentence (2) the idiom "It's not like" puts more distance between the negation and the statement being negated, so there is a chance it will be understood to mean the same as (1). However the unusual use of "some" will lead some people to wonder why it has been used, and they may decide you mean that some problems will not be caused while others might be. You should ideally use the "any" construction.